# failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i want to install laravel in linux and i got this error

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://https:/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: Please share more details. How do you actually "install laravel"? The given error message shows that there might be a misconfiguration on your system, as `http://https:/packages.json` is obviously not a valid URL to load Composer data from

Answer (score 2):

type this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel –-prefer- 
dist lara-app
```

and

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```